# How to write a CAML Query that returns folders (recursively) beneath a starting folder?

Tags: caml-query

I am looking to write a CAML query that returns all folders recursively starting at a certain folder.

CAML Designer has helped me to get this far:

```
<ViewFields>
      <FieldRef Name='FileRef' />
   </ViewFields>
   <Where>
      <And>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='ContentType' />
            <Value Type='Computed'>Folder</Value>
         </Eq>
         <Eq>
            <FieldRef Name='FSObjType' />
            <Value Type='Integer'>1</Value>
         </Eq>
      </And>
   </Where>
   <QueryOptions>
      <ViewAttributes Scope='RecursiveAll' />
   </QueryOptions>
```

This query starts at the root of the list. I want to start one level down in a particular folder. **Can someone show me how to do that?**

I thought to require that the name of the item contain /*startingfolder*/, but it seems that I can't but the `/` in the "contains" specification. **How does one specify a string that contains a '/'?**

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You need either `camlQuery.set_folderServerRelativeUrl(folderPath);` (JSOM) or `SPQuery.Folder` (Server API). Both respect the "Recursive" attribute.

MSDN references:

- [SPQuery.Folder property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.folder(v=office.15).aspx)
- [CamlQuery.FolderServerRelativeUrl property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.camlquery.folderserverrelativeurl(v=office.15).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you want items in a specific folder you can use FileDirRef column and filter based on it..

```
  <Eq>
    <FieldRef Name="FileDirRef" /> 
    <Value Type="Text">/folderPath</Value>
 </Eq>
```

Comment: I don't want the items in a particular folder. I want everything below a specific folder.